# How to add a model instance (not from db) to queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

Let's say I have a model called `Schools`.
And also I have a `Schools` instance that I don't want to store in my database.

```
temp_school = Schools(school_id='temp_1')
```

Also I have all schools

```
schools = Schools.objects.all()
```

Now, how can I add my `temp_school` to the `schools`, so that I can use it as my new queryset in my view?

Comment: Can you show your view and template?

Comment: @Lewis I don't have a template, it's ``drf``. View is just a simple view,  let's assume this queryset is inside the ``get_queryset`` function.